# benefits of the table 'wp_term_taxonomy'

Tags: taxonomy

What is the benefits of the table 'wp_term_taxonomy' in wordpress, why they don't collect all terms data in the table 'wp_terms' like that:

id name slug term_group taxonomy description parent count

what is the principle they depends on ?